# phonegap: how to check if gps is enabled

Tags: android, cordova, gps, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I want to show an alert saying that "Please turn on your GPS".

How can I get GPS status using phonegap?

I have used following code but I don't get any alert message if GPS is turned off. Instead nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <title>Device Properties Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {

   var test= navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="geolocation">   Finding geolocation...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming we're talking just about Android platform only, as [@Joerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165657/joerg) rightly says, you can use [cordova.plugins.diagnostic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic) to check if GPS is enabled using [`isGpsLocationEnabled()`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#isgpslocationenabled):

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isGpsLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
    console.log("GPS location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});
```

If the result is that GPS is switched off, you can either switch the user to the location settings page to manually enable GPS:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
```

Or, in addition, you could use [cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) to request high accuracy location mode (i.e. GPS) directly from within the app. This will show a native confirm dialog and if user agrees, GPS will be enabled automatically:

```
function onRequestSuccess(success){
    console.log("Successfully requested accuracy: "+success.message);
}

function onRequestFailure(error){
    console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
    if(error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
        if(window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
        }
    }
}

cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer. But unfortunately this plugin does not work in Phonegap Build. Whenever I include plugin in config.xml it fails with error for android.

Comment: I don't use Phonegap Build (I build locally), but I'd be interested to know what the error is and if I can fix it. I'd be grateful if you could open an issue on the [plugin's github repo](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) and paste the log output from Phonegap Build containing the error details.

Comment: Please review issue from https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy/issues/3

Comment: I accepted your answer. 
What about ios? How can we trigger this kind of popup or how can we at least chck gps for ios as well?

Comment: iOS doesn't distinguish between high-accuracy (GPS) or low-accuracy(Network) - it's simply "Location". You can use the diagnostic plugin to check [isLocationEnabled()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#islocationenabled) and if not, the best we can do is [switchToSettings](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#switchtosettings) to allow user to manually enable it.

Comment: Note it's possible to natively invoke such a dialog on iOS by requesting a location, but this is something cordova-plugin-geolocation doesn't currently support - see [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10478)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103289/discussion-between-user2899728-and-davealden).

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is **below**.

<s>*You cannot check *if gps is enabled**</s>

**You can set a timeout and get the timeout.**
You can do this by setting the `timeout` parameter in the [geolocationoptions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation#geolocationoptions) parameter. (which you did not use)

From the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation#geolocationoptions)

- **timeout:** The maximum length of time (milliseconds) that is allowed to pass from the call to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` or `geolocation.watchPosition` until the corresponding `geolocationSuccess` callback executes. If the `geolocationSuccess` callback is not invoked within this time, the `geolocationError` callback is passed a `PositionError.TIMEOUT` error code. (Note that when used in conjunction with `geolocation.watchPosition`, the `geolocationError` callback could be called on an interval every `timeout` milliseconds!) *(Number)*

### WAIT I WAS WRONG

There is now a plugin that checks to see if the GPS is turned on.

In fact, more than one.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fastrde-checkgps
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-gpsdetect

Comment: Thanks for response. Can we trigger to turn gps on in android using phonegap?

Comment: @user2899728 if the answer resolved your issue, could you check mark the answer 'accepted'.

Comment: can you please suggest that how can I trigger a gps setting popup so that user can turn it on within app ?

Comment: Have you tested both plugins? They didn't work for me. So i am trying to get the right way to use Diagnostic plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to check if GPS, Wifi, … is enabled, is to use this plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic

Using this plugin you can check a lot of features and you can switch the user to the settings.

Comment: I had being using isLocationEnabled() from Diagnostic Plugin, but if my Gps is Off, the function goes to the success callback. Do i must use isGpsLocationEnabled() and isNetworkLocationEnabled() instead of? What is the difference?